# Error while receiving inapp message in android SDk 8.0.7

Tags: android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, salesforce-sdk-android, in-app-guidance

My app is receiving push messages but is unable to receive in-app messages. I have implemented everything from the documentation.

1. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/in-app-message/in-app-messaging.html
2. Multiple push -https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/multiple-push-sdks.html

But after getting inapp message I get following error.

```
2023-01-05 18:31:40.009 27603-27913/com.capty.wedbox E/~!InboxMessageManager: Failed to parse inbox messages response - Sdk Version: 8.0.7
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:460)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:101)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:168)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:185)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.inbox.c.a(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.inbox.a.a(Unknown Source:60)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.http.c$b.a(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.internal.g.run(Unknown Source:17)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

My SDK state

```
    2023-01-05 19:32:31.758 30475-30475/com.capty.wedbox I/~#SdkState: initConfig: MarketingCloudConfig(applicationId=xxxxxxxx, accessToken=xxxxx, senderId=null, marketingCloudServerUrl=https://mcywc37f654knfqm53-qhdmyt8y4.device.marketingcloudapis.com/, mid=xxx, analyticsEnabled=true, geofencingEnabled=true, inboxEnabled=true, piAnalyticsEnabled=true, proximityEnabled=true, markMessageReadOnInboxNotificationOpen=true, delayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet=false, useLegacyPiIdentifier=true, notificationCustomizationOptions={smallIconResId=2131165724, launchIntentProvider=null, channelIdProvider=null}, proximityNotificationCustomizationOptions=null, urlHandler=com.capty.wedbox.App$$ExternalSyntheticLambda11@75aa372, appPackageName=com.capty.wedbox, appVersionName=1.7.17, predictiveIntelligenceServerUrl=https://510003420.collect.igodigital.com/c2/510003420/process_batch.json)
2023-01-05 19:32:31.758 30475-30475/com.capty.wedbox I/~#SdkState: initStatus: InitializationStatus(status=COMPLETED_WITH_DEGRADED_FUNCTIONALITY, unrecoverableException=null, locationsError=true, playServicesStatus=-1, playServicesMessage=null, encryptionChanged=false, storageError=false, proximityError=true, messagingPermissionError=false, sslProviderEnablementError=false, initializedComponents=[BehaviorManager, LifecycleManager, RequestManager, AlarmScheduler, SyncRoute, ControlChannel, ConfigComponent, LocationManager, ProximityManager, AnalyticsManager, InboxMessageManager, NotificationManager, RegionMessageManager, PushMessageManager, RegistrationManager, InAppMessageManager, Event], isUsable=true)
2023-01-05 19:32:31.758 30475-30475/com.capty.wedbox I/~#SdkState: PushMessageManager: {
      "pushEnabled": true,
      "pushPermissionsAllowed": true,
      "debugInfo": {
        "senderId": null,
        "deviceToken": "xxxxx",
        "firebaseApps": [
          "FirebaseApp{name=[DEFAULT], options=FirebaseOptions{applicationId=1:xxx:android:xxx, apiKey=xxxxx, databaseUrl=xxx, gcmSenderId=xxx, storageBucket=xx, projectId=xxx}}"
        ],
        "c2dmReceiver": [
          {
            "name": "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver",
            "priority": 0
          }
        ],
        "instanceIdService": [],
        "messagingService": [
          {
            "name": "com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.push.MCFirebaseMessagingService",
            "priority": -1
          },
          {
            "name": "com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService",
            "priority": -500
          }
        ]
      }
    }
2023-01-05 19:32:31.758 30475-30475/com.capty.wedbox I/~#SdkState: RegistrationManager: {
      "current_registration": {
        "deviceID": "xxxx",
        "device_Token": "xxxx",
        "sdk_Version": "8.0.7",
        "app_Version": "1.7.17 : 296",
        "dST": false,
        "location_Enabled": true,
        "proximity_Enabled": false,
        "platform_Version": "12",
        "push_Enabled": true,
        "timeZone": "21600",
        "platform": "Android",
        "hwid": "Google Pixel 6a",
        "etAppId": "xxx",
        "locale": "en_US",
        "tags": [
          "ALL",
          "Android",
          "DEBUG"
        ],
        "attributes": [
          {
            "key": "EmailAddress",
            "value": "hossain.zobaerx@gmail.com"
          },
          {
            "key": "External_ID",
            "value": "xxxx"
          },
          {
            "key": "First Name",
            "value": "Zobaer host t t"
          },
          {
            "key": "Last Name",
            "value": "Hossain"
          }
        ]
      },
      "last_sent_timestamp": "2023-01-05T12:20:11.271Z"
    }
2023-01-05 19:32:31.758 30475-30475/com.capty.wedbox I/~#SdkState: InAppMessageManager: {
      "messages": [],
      "subscriberToken": "xxxxxxxx",
      "custom_font_set": false,
      "status_bar_color": 0
    }
2023-01-05 19:32:31.758 30475-30475/com.capty.wedbox I/~#SdkState: InApp Messages: []
2023-01-05 19:32:31.758 30475-30475/com.capty.wedbox I/~#SdkState: InApp Events: {
      "triggers": []
    }
```

Comment: Clarification: Inbox and InApp are entirely different products. You are having an issue with Inbox Messaging, not InApp Messaging. Please open a support ticket.

Comment: Sorry, can you help me with where I can open a support ticket?

Comment: Through your support representative or account manager.